# Generic License for Licensing Artwork

Tags: licensing

Are there a selection of freely available licenses which can be used to license artwork?

Essentially the license would need to cover the following:

- Allow me to sell artwork to consumer on a non-exclusive (but royalty-free) basis.
- Allow consumer to use artwork in a single commercial or non-commercial project.
- Disallow consumer from redistributing the artwork beyond the scope of their project.
- Demand that copyright information is left intact.

I am new to this and am not aware of any further requirements of such a license. Any advice on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, those 4 bullet points would make a decent license. Easy to read, easy to understand, and short enough that people may actually read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AIGA Standard Form of Agreement](http://www.aiga.org/standard-agreement/) is a good starting point. See Schedule A: "Intellectual Property Provisions." You can take language straight out of that and use it. The AIGA is an excellent resource for contract, copyright, rate and other information.

Truth be told, if you took your bullet list and reworded it slightly, it would make a simple and clear licensing agreement. Note that you are *not* "selling" your artwork, you are *licensing* it to the consumer for a particular use on the specific terms you outline. The distinction is important.

If you expect a lot of money to be involved, it would not hurt to consult a copyright attorney on whatever final wording you come up with, just to be safe.

Comment: the license is only for low cost 'stock' artwork. We just wanted some writing to go with each sale to a) cover use / misuse of the artwork and b) protect our copyright. Thanks for the link, I will have a thorough read through that.